Isekai manga in which an engineer/architect (not sure which) is reincarnated as the son of an influential noble, whose mother is a sword master
Lost the name while moving to a new phone. As stated in the title, it's about either an engineer or an architect who gets reincarnated as the son of an influential noble (fairly sure he's a duke, but not 100%),  whose mother is a sword master.
His mother was an adventurer whom his father hired as part of a subjugation; they fought, then got married. Still at a young age (like between 5-15), he needs money for a reason I forget, so he "invents" a hand pump for the well after some trouble shooting. Any part touching water is copper so it doesn't degrade as it rusts, with the solution to the problem being a wooden section to keep the different metals of the pipe and pump separate. While the pumps are revolutionary and an effort is made to get them in every village, the production is too slow.
He decides to make sugar from sugar beats and hires adventurers because the production method for sugar isn't known in the kingdom yet and all sugar is imported, making it expensive.
There's a lot in the middle here I'm forgetting, but he ends up as lord of a territory that sticks out into the next country like a sore thumb. The lord of the neighboring land in the other country makes plans to invade; the protagonist catches wind and prepares trenches, barbed wire, makeshift flamethrowers, and keeps it as secret as possible.
That's all I remember story-wise, but I remember it had around at least 50 chapters when I last read it, which was months ago.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

Is this Multi-Mind Mayhem: Isekai Tensei Soudouki...?

Bard Cornelius: the son of a nobleman of Mauricia, an empire located in a parallel universe. But Bard is no ordinary boy―he’s got three souls packed into one body! Aside from his own consciousness, he’s got Oka Sanai, a miserly samurai, and Masaharu Oka, a high school otaku who loves animal ears. With his extra knowledge of military tactics and business acumen, Bard’s ready to cheat his way to the top!

A modern Japanese high school student and a feudal Japanese soldier die and their souls are transmigrated into the body of Balud Cornelius, the son of a nobleman of Mauricia, a kingdom in another world.
In chapter 2, Balud harvests a crop of sugar beets he's grown in order to make and sell sugar.



In chapter 20, he makes a hand pump, which is subsequently mass-produced.
In chapter 25, it's explained how his father, a count, and his mother, a mercenary and swordswoman, met and fell in love while defending the kingdom of Mauricia from the neighbouring kingdom of Haurelia.
In chapter 42, the King of Mauricia bestows the title of viscount on Balud and appoints him as the Lord of Antrim, the easternmost tip of Mauricia which juts out into the neighbouring kingdom of Haurelia.
In chapter 49, Balud has his subordinates fortify Antrim with ditches and barbed wire fences.
In chapter 64, Antrim is being invaded by an army from Haurelia, and Balud has his troops defend their territory with flamethrowers.



